# Select2 TypeError: data.results is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

Am trying to use Select2 to load remote data using ajax / json but i keep getting an error as:

> TypeError: data.results is undefined

My code is :

```
$('#tags').select2({
                ajax: {
                    url: 'http://localhost:8090/getallusers',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    quietMillis: 100,
                    data: function (term) {
                        return {
                            term: term
                        };
                    },
                    results: function (data) {
                        return data;
                        }

                    }

            });
```

I really Don’t Understand the Problem !

Comment: How your **data** value is returned in the result function?

Comment: Its like this : [{"id":1,"first_name":"hassan","last_name":"alnator","age":24,"picture":null,"last_in":0,"last_out":0,"username":"halnator","password":"123","user_type":"user"},{"id":2,"first_name":"fareed","last_name":"nam","age":22,"picture":null,"last_in":0,"last_out":0,"username":"fareed","password":"123","user_type":"user"}]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Select2 needs the results as a collection of objects with id: and text: attributes.

Like:

> [{ 'id': 1, 'text': 'Demo' }, { 'id': 2, 'text': 'Demo 2'}]

Try, to reformat you response like:

```
$('#tags').select2({
    ajax: {
        url: 'http://localhost:8090/getallusers',
        dataType: 'json',
        quietMillis: 100,
        data: function (term) {
            return {
                term: term
            };
        },
        results: function (data) {
            var myResults = [];
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                myResults.push({
                    'id': item.id,
                    'text': item.first_name + " " + item.last_name
                });
            });
            return {
                results: myResults
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Great Thank you , Now am getting Results but i still cant click on any result and select the one i wont , and i still dont understand the problem ?

Comment: No errors , am getting Results but am trying to click on one so i can select it but its not selecting the result

Comment: The Problem Was that i was not mapping to the id provided in the json returned , , in the example you have id returned in the json and you are trying to get the 'item.ID' so it should be 'item.id' thnx

Comment: Good catch, and sorry for the typo, I'll fix it